# Does not have default value exception in Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, spring-security

I could not insert any data to my DbUser.groovy domain class. When Iam calling the below method.

```html
 def insertDbuserDetails(Map Hmap){
  try{
   def emp = Employee.get(Hmap.get("empId"))
   if(emp){
   def Username = springSecurityService.getPrincipal().getUsername()
   def row = DbUser.findByEmployee(emp)
   if(!row){
   def data = new DbUser(employee:emp,username:Hmap.get("userName"),password:Hmap.get("password"),client:Hmap.get("client"),create_id:Username,create_dt:new Date(),mod_id:null,mod_dt:null)
   data.save(failOnError: true)
   return data
   }else{
   return "exist"
   }
    }else{
    return "invalid"
    }
  }
   catch(Exception e){
   println("Exception in getDbuserDetails() of DbuserService.groovy: "+e);
   }
  }
```

it gives me an error like

> Error |
>   2017-02-10 18:44:08,307 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] ERROR spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - Field 'employee' doesn't have a default value
>   Exception in getDbuserDetails() of DbuserService.groovy: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Hibernate operation: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; Field 'employee' doesn't have a default value; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Field 'employee' doesn't have a default value
>
> Error |
>   2017-02-10 18:44:08,328 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] ERROR hibernate.AssertionFailure  - HHH000099: an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session): org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in com.domain.gcg.DbUser entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
>
> Error |
>   2017-02-10 18:44:08,469 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - AssertionFailure occurred when processing request: [POST] /UserManagement/dbuser/addDbuserDetails - parameters:
>   Repassword: pass123
>   client: testclient
>   password: pass123
>   empId: SE357
>   empName: Abhilash Shajan
>   username: Abhi123
>   null id in com.domain.gcg.DbUser entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs). Stacktrace follows:
>   Message: null id in com.domain.gcg.DbUser entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)

Here is my DbUser.groovy domain class

```html
class DbUser {
  
 Employee employee
 String client
 String username
 String password
 String create_id
 Date create_dt
 String mod_id
 Date mod_dt
 
 static mapping = {
  version true
  dynamicUpdate true
  password type: GormEncryptedStringType
                employee column: '`employee`',generator: 'foreign', params: [ property: 'employee'], insertable: false, updateable: false
   }

 static constraints = {
  mod_id(nullable: true)
  mod_dt(nullable: true)
 }
```

Can some one help me?

Comment: This is the same question as before. Did you try to recreate the database as I suggested? (just delete all tables and run grails application anew and let it create tables again.

Comment: @MikelisBaltruks I deleted my database and created a fresh one but the problem is still exist. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Check your mapping, you have insertable and updateable = false on the employee field and you are trying to update this field.

Comment: This was the issue for me! great answer.